# The Component menu contains a Categories entry pointing to com_weblink which doesn't exist

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

So it displays a error:
Error loading component: com_weblinks, Component not found.
It's a site migrated from a 2.5 one, which was the migration of a 1.5 one.
I've tried installing/uninstalling the Web Links Manager from JED but that didn't work.
How can I suppress this menu entry (I don't need Web Links) ?
Regards
jc

Comment: Hm this is in the menu module.  I believe it is probably reading the extensions table to get the list. Try going to the extensions manager and see if Weblinks is there. Disable it. See if that fixes the problem. You can also uninstall it but I'd try disabling first.

Comment: Sorry, no Weblinks in the extensions manager...

Comment: Can you look in your database and see if it is in the extensions table?  You are talking about the administrator menu drop down right?

Comment: No, it is not in the extensions table...  And yes in the back-end Components menu, it is the 2nd entry of the menu...

Comment: Ok but you see how the menu is created right? https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/administrator/modules/mod_menu/helper.php#L76

Comment: Thanks 4 the link ! There's no com_weblink BUT a com_categories: (6, 'com_categories', 'component', 'com_categories', '', 1, 1, 1, 1, '{"name":"com_categories","type":"component","creationDate":"December 2007","author":"Joomla! Project","copyright":"(C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.","authorEmail":"admin@joomla.org","authorUrl":"www.joomla.org","version":"3.0.0","description":"COM_CATEGORIES_XML_DESCRIPTION","group":""}', '', '', '', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0),    NB: the URL of the menu entry is index.php?option=com_categories&extension=extension=com_weblinks ...

Comment: Are there any weblinks categories in the categories table? (look at the extensions field).   By the way there is a whole separate joomla stack exchange site joomla.stackexchange.com [joomla.se] and you might want to search/ask there.

Comment: OK I'll look there. Many thanks for your help Elin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incorrect menu entry was in the #__menu table. Don't know where it came from. Just deleted it.
HTH